# links one row in desktop/tablet, two columns in mobile?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page section with links that should like this on desktop/mobile:

```
link link link link link link
```

But this on mobile

```
link    link
link    link
link    link
```

Can you offer any suggestions on how to get this working in bootstrap? I'm using HTML like the following now.  Would different HTML help aybe?

```
<span class="col-xs-12 text-center" >
    <a href="http://link" class=" col-xs-6" >link</a>
    <a href="http://link" class=" col-xs-6" >link</a>
    <a href="http://link" class=" col-xs-6" >link</a>
    <a href="http://link" class=" col-xs-6" >link</a>
    <a href="http://link" class=" col-xs-6" >link</a>
    <a href="http://link" class=" col-xs-6" >link</a>
</span>
```

Comment: You can't have columns as children of columns without a layer of `row`. See https://github.com/twbs/bootlint/wiki/E014

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="row">
  <span class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
    <a href="http://link" class="col-md-2 col-xs-6">link</a>
    <a href="http://link" class="col-md-2 col-xs-6">link</a>
    <a href="http://link" class="col-md-2 col-xs-6">link</a>
    <a href="http://link" class="col-md-2 col-xs-6">link</a>
    <a href="http://link" class="col-md-2 col-xs-6">link</a>
    <a href="http://link" class="col-md-2 col-xs-6">link</a>
  </span>
</div>
```

If you want them to have the same single line structure in mobile, use `col-xs-2`

[**Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/YCM34sKhLo)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as below:

```
<span class="col-xs-12 text-center" >
    <a href="http://link" class="col-xs-6 col-md-2" >link</a>
    <a href="http://link" class="col-xs-6 col-md-2" >link</a>
    <a href="http://link" class="col-xs-6 col-md-2" >link</a>
    <a href="http://link" class="col-xs-6 col-md-2" >link</a>
    <a href="http://link" class="col-xs-6 col-md-2" >link</a>
    <a href="http://link" class="col-xs-6 col-md-2" >link</a>
</span>
```

Comment: `col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-lg-2` is redundant; just use `col-xs-6 col-md-2`. See https://github.com/twbs/bootlint/wiki/E029

Comment: Is there any way to override this behavior?  What if I only want col-xs-6 to apply to mobile & that is it?

Comment: @MrSmith.. All these `col-*-*` are defined for particular screen sizes. `xs` for **extra small screen**, `sm` for **small screen**, `md` for **medium screen** and `lg` for **large screen**. I don't under stand your point of applying `col-xs-6` only for mobile!!